# Can we achieve the below behavior while sorting an array of string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

I have an array like this.

```
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.3', 'A1.2', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.3 (3)', 'A1.2 (3)']
```

Current sorting makes it like this. I have tried sort() method.

```
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.2', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.2 (3)', 'A1.3', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.3 (3)']
```

I need the result to be like this.

```
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.2', 'A1.3', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.2 (3)', 'A1.3 (3)']
```

Comment: Is this the _actual_ content of the arrays, or are you using this as a simplified example (Before someone writes soemthing to parse this data and then you say "Actually thats just an example, my real data is XXX")

Comment: This is 99% similar to my data. I have tried and failed to group and sort based on the requirement. If there is a method to sort which results in the required pattern, it would help in my real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to temporarily map each string in such a way that the number between parentheses is moved to the front of the string, and if there is not such a part, to put "0" in that position.

Then apply a natural sort on that using the capabilities of the `Intl` native object:

```js
function map(s) {
    // put the part in parentheses at the front of the string,
    //    defaulting to 0:
    return ("0." + s).replace(/^0(.*)\((.*)\)$/, "$2$1");
}

// Define a collator for natural sorting:
let collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: "base"
});

// demo
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.3', 'A1.2', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.3 (3)', 'A1.2 (3)'];

arr.sort((a, b) => collator.compare(map(a), map(b)));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start off by using regex to parse the data of each element inside ther `sort` and then use whatever logic you want to pick apart the sort logic

This regex for example:

```
([A-Z])(\d+.\d)(?:\s\((\d+)\))?
```

Will get each part of your element into 2 or 3 groups

eg

```
["A1.2", "A", "1.2", undefined)
```

or

```
["A1.2 (2)", "A", "1.2", "2")
```

Then just apply some logic.

```js
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.3', 'A1.2', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.3 (3)', 'A1.2 (3)']
let re = /([A-Z])(\d+.\d)(?:\s\((\d+)\))?/

const result = arr.sort ( (a,b) => {
  const aMatch = a.match(re);
  const bMatch = b.match(re);
  
  const suffix = parseInt(aMatch[3] || "0", 10) - parseInt(bMatch[3] || "0", 10);
  if(suffix != 0)
    return suffix
  const res = parseFloat(aMatch[2]) - parseFloat(bMatch[2]);
  return res;  
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more example, will work *just in case that your data is really close to the provided example*:

```
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.3', 'A1.2', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.3 (3)', 'A1.2 (3)']

function sort_special(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '').split('').reverse().join('') - b.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '').split('').reverse().join(''));
}
f = arr.sort(sort_special);
console.log(f);
```

```js
let arr = ['A1.1', 'A1.3', 'A1.2', 'A1.1 (2)', 'A1.3 (2)', 'A1.2 (2)', 'A1.1 (3)', 'A1.3 (3)', 'A1.2 (3)']

function sort_special(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '').split('').reverse().join('') - b.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '').split('').reverse().join(''));
}
f = arr.sort(sort_special);
console.log(f);
```